# Maximum macro count per layer Kinesis Advantage

Tags: macros, dvorak, kinesis-advantage

Maximum macro count of a kinesis advantage2 keyboard layer seems to be 128. I tried to reproduce the full programmer dvorak layout without success. After creating the file with over 400 macros (ctrl, shift and alt, plus simultaneous) it just reverted to 128 bindings, and after that recording new macros simply doesn't work. This obvious limitation is only vaguely reported in the documentation (p. 7: "hundreds of heavy duty macros") (latest: 01-07-19) and I have not been able to find it on the web.

Is there another way to reach the desired result of having a portable completely programmed programmer dvorak result for the Kinesis Advantage2?

Comment: Is there a reason why you are trying to reprogram the keyboard with macros instead of doing something like just installing the keyboard layout in Windows?

Comment: My own computer has the keyboard layout installed, in both Windows and Linux (in Linux tty & gui), but I want to be able to attach my keyboard anywhere and have the layout available to me without having to select the keyboard layout in the software configuration of the computer its attached to.